# Cannot create instance of object in controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, email, activerecord

I'm attempting to validate and save an email from a form with three parameters: :name, :email, and :message, and then send the entire email. Currently, the email will send successfully without validating the parameters or creating an instance of Email.

Controller

```
def thank_you
    @name = params[:name]
    @email = params[:email]
    @message = params[:message] || "Hello!"

    if Email.create(name: @name, email: @email, message: @message)

      ActionMailer::Base.mail(
          :from => @email, 
            :to => 'erikvdw@comcast.net', 
            :subject => "A new contact form message from #{@name}", 
            :body => @message).deliver
    end
  end
```

Model

```
class Email < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates_presence_of :name
  validates_format_of :email, :with => /\A([^@\s]+)@((?:[-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,})\z/i
  validates_length_of :message, :maximum => 500, :minimum => 10
end
```

View

```
<%= form_tag("/thank_you") do %>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-5">
                      <div class="input-group">
                          <%= text_field_tag :name, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Name' %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-7">
                      <div class="input-group">
                        <span class="input-group-addon" id="basic-addon1">@</span>
                        <%= text_field_tag :email, nil, class: 'form-control', placeholder: 'Your Email Address' %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <div class="row">
                    <div class="col-md-12">
                      <div class="input-group text-area-wide">
                        <%= text_area_tag :message, nil, class: 'form-control text-area-wide', placeholder: 'When are you available?' %>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                  <br>
                  <%= submit_tag 'Get Started', class: 'btn btn-success' %>
                  <p><a href="http://www.skype.com/en/" target="_blank">Skype</a> required</p>
                <% end %>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think your problem in the operation

```html
Email.create
```

because it's creating a instance in memory and don't save the instance to DB.
You must call save method or check validation method directly - email.valid?, like this:

```html
 email = Email.create(name: @name, email: @email, message: @message)
if email.valid?
  #send email
end
```